# When to use SESSION and when to use GET for parameter passing in a web application?

Tags: php, rest, web-applications, get, session-variables

Is there a guideline as to when to use GET and when to use SESSION to pass parameters in a web app from one page to the next?

Example:

a web-app has a "sales quote" entity that you can "open", add items to it, and close.  You can open another quote, add items to that quote, etc.  While on that quote, adding, deleting, editing items, the database layer needs to know which areas of the table to read from and which table to write to, to ensure the items get add added to the right quote.  That can be accomplished by using a `quote_id`.

Should that quote id be passed via `GET` or via `SESSION`?

Comment: are they logged in to the site at this point?

Comment: yes, user is logged in at that point

Comment: then i would use the URL for friendly bookmarking

Comment: session data is not *"passed"* between the server and the client, they are stored at the server side. you set them as your application needs (e.g the count of failed login tries). Get parameters on the other hand are in the control of the client(e.g: the locale the client wants to show the interface in)

Answer (score -1):

Session is primarily used to store user information   like username ,theme etc across multiple pages.
GET and her sisters POST, PUT and DELETE are HTTP methods or verbs they are technicaly types of requests going from clients such as web browsers to the server.
When you generate a wep page in the server you should insert quote_id as a hidden input in your form or attribute value of a tag  when there is more JS work going or appending it to the request url like GET /quotes/5 where 5 is your quote_id so you would do somthing like this in the server to generate anchor that when clicked will retrieve a quote by its id

```
     <a href="<?php echo '/quotes/'.$quote_id ?>" 
       > click me to get quote info </a>
```

-EDIT:add a clearer exampl

```
    <a href="<?php echo 
   '/route/get_quote_by_id.php?
 quote_id='.$quote_id ?>" 
           > click me to get quote info </a>
```

and  in your get_quote_by_id.php:

```
echo $_GET['quote_id'];
```

Comment: SESSION is not analogue to GET